# Convert Json array to Assosiative array and bind it to AutoCompleteTextView -- Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have an array like below ..

```
[{"InstituteID":"1","InstituteName":"Demo Institute"},{"InstituteID":"16","InstituteName":"Sheridan College"},{"InstituteID":"17","InstituteName":"iCent Prosp"},{"InstituteID":"18","InstituteName":"Seneca College"}]
```

I want to convert this array to associative and i want to set the institution name to AutoCompleteTextView.

here is my code

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String res) {

        try {

            JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(res);
            String status=responseObject.getString("Status");
            JSONArray detailsArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("InstituteList");

            String[] newarray = new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(detailsArray),String[].class);

            Log.i("Institute register assc" , String.valueOf(newarray));

            if(status.equals("true")) {

  autoTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.instname_field);
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ProgLanguages);
                autoTextView.setThreshold(1);
                autoTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response successful",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

HERE IS MY CODE OF AUTOCOMPLETE VIEW IN XML File..

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/autoCompt"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/instname_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="Type Institution Name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="#b8d1e5"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:ems="10"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks...

Added log

[image]

Comment: You have to use custom autocomplete textview for achieve it

Comment: can u please tell me how that possible.

Comment: Is that any error in your code? what is the result for current code?

Comment: Please look at my answer it might helpful for you

Comment: @JishadP : what value u are getting in log for `Log.i("Institute register assc" , String.valueOf(newarray));` line?

Comment: the app is stoping when added the line. not getting any response.

Comment: @RemeesMSyde, now ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newarray);  showing as red

Comment: @JishadP You told that Log.i("Institute register assc" , String.valueOf(newarray)); is stopping the app, please check the log and let us know what type of error is that.

Comment: @RemeesMSyde   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3

Comment: @RemeesMSyde, added log in question

Comment: Actually u need to set the institute name to the auto complete text view right? Then why your passing "ProgLanguages" to the adapter?

Comment: @RemeesMSyde, thst is a demo please ignore that...

Comment: @JishadP Dude my answer is same as the accepted answer and i posted it first. Why dont you accept or +1 it.

Comment: @RemeesMSyde, Currently i am referring ur code. but its not getting what i needs, I want the institutionId fro that time. how can i get that ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Here i changes the method you used for getting the institution name array. This may work for you.

```
    JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(res);
    String status=responseObject.getString("Status");
    ArrayList<String> listInstituteNames = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    JSONArray detailsArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("InstituteList");

    for (int i = 0; i <detailsArray.length() ; i++) {

          JSONObject obj = detailsArray.getJSONObject(i)

          listInstituteNames.add(obj.getString("InstituteName"))

    }

    autoTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.instname_field);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listInstituteNames);
    autoTextView.setThreshold(1);
    autoTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create custom autocomplete view

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteView extends AutoCompleteTextView
{

public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode)
{
    String filterText = "";
    super.performFiltering(filterText, keyCode);
}
}
```

Use custom ArrayAdapter for that

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AutoCompleteBean>
```

than after bind it

Answer (score -1):

just retreive all the institute name to string array and pass it
no need to use json for this simple

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(res);
String status=responseObject.getString("Status");
JSONArray detailsArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("InstituteList");

String[] instituteNames = new String[detailsArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i <detailsArray.length() ; i++) {

      JSONObject obj = detailsArray.getJSONObject(i)

      //save the each institute name to this String[]
      instituteNames[i]=obj.getString("InstituteName");

}

autoTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.instname_field);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(<Activity-Name>.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, instituteNames); //and pass here..
autoTextView.setThreshold(1);
autoTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```